# Mudar input radio checked pelo Jquery

Tags: jquery, css3, slider, css-animations

Estou com mais uma duvida aqui no fórum rs.
Eu criei um framework pure css, fiz um slider com input radio + label mais não tinha colocado animação (mudar de segundo em segundo entre eles).

Mais só q agora (usando ele em um cliente) vi que ficou muito chato pois esta estático tendo que a pessoa clicar nas setinhas para mudar de imgs

Queria fazer a animação com CSS3, mais não consegui montar animação.
Se alguem souber como fazer em CSS3 ou Jquery poderia me ajudar.

```
<div id="slider" class="slider-danger">
    <input name="slider" id="slider1" type="radio">
    <input name="slider" id="slider2" type="radio">
    <input name="slider" id="slider3" type="radio">
    <input name="slider" id="slider4" type="radio">
    <input name="slider" id="slider5" type="radio" checked="checked">

    <article id="slide1">
        <img src="imgs/slider/sliderimg1.jpg">
    </article>

    <article id="slide2">
        <img src="imgs/slider/sliderimg2.jpg">
    </article>

    <article id="slide3">
        <img src="imgs/slider/sliderimg3.jpg">
    </article>

    <article id="slide4">
        <img src="imgs/slider/sliderimg4.jpg">
    </article>


    <div id="controls">
        <label for="slide1" class="arrows"></label>
        <label for="slide2" class="arrows"></label>
        <label for="slide3" class="arrows"></label>
        <label for="slide4" class="arrows"></label>
        <label for="slide5" class="arrows"></label>
    </div>
```

O framework é este: https://github.com/TwoSheep/blackcat
Um exemplo dele em uso é este: spflbrasil.com

O que eu quero é mudar de check no input radio de segundo em segundo. Eu sei que da para mudar .ckecked no jquery, mais nao consegui montar para mais de dois checked.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Cara, são duas perguntas? Você quer montar um slider (mudando o checked a cada segundo) ou quer uma animação em CSS3?

Comment: Uma pergunta só. O slide ja esta pronto (estrutura q coloquei), só quero por meio do jquery mudar o checked acada certo segundo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer uma tarefa que se repete em intervalos constantes, você pode usar o `setInterval`. Tem um exemplo abaixo, só pra dar uma ideia mesmo, mas aconselho que você dê uma lida nos seguintes links:

Primeiro, pra entender o `setInterval`:
http://nodebr.com/funcoes-temporizadoras-embutidas-no-javascript-settimeout-e-setinterval/

Depois, dá uma olhada no `jQuery` pra entender um pouco melhor como ele funciona: http://i18n.2kminterativa.com.br/jquery/jquery-getting-started-pt_br.html

```js
var radioAtivo = 0;
var qtdDeRadios = 5;
var intervaloEntreRadios = 1000; //milisegundos
var radios = $('input');

window.setInterval(function(){
   radios[radioAtivo].checked = true;
   radioAtivo++;
   if (radioAtivo >= qtdDeRadios) radioAtivo = 0;
}, intervaloEntreRadios)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="radio" type="radio" />
<input name="radio" type="radio" />
<input name="radio" type="radio" />
<input name="radio" type="radio" />
<input name="radio" type="radio" />
```

Comment: Nosssssaaaa!
Muito obrigado, você me ajudou e muito, muito muito rsrs